# How to identify more than one value in the method using suds python

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

Hi How to identify more than one value in the particular method.For example my method will take two values to send some balance(eg: amount and account number). I did for one value and I am getting errors if method has more than one value

```
   url='http://www.testfire.net/bank/ws.asmx?WSDL'
   client = Client(url)
   print client
   for method in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods.values():
        print "the existing methods in webservice are:"       +method.name                                        
   while True:
    try:
       s = raw_input("Enter the name of the method you want to scan: ")
       name= getattr(client.service,s)
       break 
    except suds.MethodNotFound as e:
        print "Please enter a valid method."
   value=raw_input("enter a value for method: ")
   result=name(value)
   print result
```

Pls provide suggestions

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your code?

Comment: Are you sure? The line `print Client` isn't aligned correctly with the following or preceding lines, and you alternate between indenting with anything from 1 space to 5 spaces, instead of the conventional 4 spaces per indent.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Did Changes